# Migrate Mac to Mac with external iTunes & iPhoto

Tags: external-disk, migration

I've got an iMac with 2 external hard drives.
One 1.5TB external hard drive for iTunes and iPhoto (750GB combined) and one 3TB external hard drive for Time Machine backups.

I want to migrate everything to my new MacBook Pro which has 512GB storage.

How can I do this? Migrate assistant won't work because there is not enough storage on my MacBook.

Or can I just plug the external hard drives into my MacBook and select them as my iTunes & iPhoto library?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just plugin your external hard drives and start iTunes and iPhoto with the option key hold to select your library